# How to mock instances created by a service?

Tags: java, mockito

I'm using mockito. My service is creating instance of Runnable classe and then schedule the run of it using Spring Scheduler.

I want to test the service and so verify that the "run" method is called but since the instance is created in the service I cannot mock it (or don't know how).
How can I do? Is it possible with mockito?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say, because it may really depend on the architecture of your service, but I would try to separate the creation of an instance of Runnable and the scheduling of its run.

That way you have two different units that will be simpler to test.

If it is hard to unit tests your methods, you may want to split them.

Comment: Good point, I can make my Runnable as singleton so I will be able to mock them. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused as to what you are attempting to verify here. The service should not care that `run` is called, but rather that Scheduler is informed of the work it needs to do. So you should mock the scheduler and insure that it is given the right Runnable.

That run is called is part of the scheduler, which you should be able to assume is well tested code that does not require you do double check it works.

Comment: You are probably right but I like to test features as a black box. I mean, the service is to run stuff at a given time so that's what I want to test. I don't care how it's done so I don't know that it is using Spring scheduler, and so I don't want to mock and test the scheduler.

Comment: I don't see how you can marry together "test as a black box" an adding mocks. Sure fake services, but mocks are the opposite to "black box" IMO. Again, I'm not sure what you are attempting to verify here, that the service works, in which case it using Spring Scheduler is a vital part of that. If it is something that is using your service, then don't mock Spring, mock your service.